Estimating the Distribution of Bumblebee Flower Visits from Partial Observations
bumblebee visiting lavender bush
In our garden, we have a lavender bush that is very popular with bumblebees (the picture was taken by me).
During the summer, there's a lot of activity, and I enjoy watching the bumblebees at work.
I am curious about the distribution of flower visits. However, measuring this poses a challenge:
It's nearly impossible to track when a bumblebee arrives and then start counting its visits.
Therefore, I rely on the following method:
I randomly pick a bumblebee and count the number of flower visits until it leaves the bush.
Now, I have a list of these partial flower visit counts, and I have the following questions:
Is it possible to approximate the underlying distribution through many such observations?
If so, how? (My naive approach would be to simply double each observed count.)
Is this problem related to other similar observation problems?
Thank you for your answers!

Ordinarily, pictures aren't appropriate for the site, but I like that one.  That said, I am not sure what you are measuring, nor what you want to measure.    I think that you want the distribution of bee visits to a particular flower (presumably Poisson, so you just want the average).  Is that right?  But, I don't see how watching a particular bee helps.  Say he(?) skips a particular flower.  What does that tell you?  Or have I misunderstood completely?

As a possibly relevant side issue, I wouldn't imagine that the distribution is the same for each flower.  I don't know bees terribly well, but I know humming birds and they have their serious favorites.  Makes no sense that I can spot but they will all favor one blossom and ignore the (seemingly) equivalent ones right next to it.

Sorry maybe I was not specific enough.
When the bees visit the bush they hop from one blossom to the next until they have collected enough. I want the distribution of blossom visits of one trip from the nest and back. The problem is I have to start counting somewhere in the middle of the trip.

Still not clear.  Do you mean something like "a bee will typically visit a number of blossoms on a single trip and I want to analyze the distribution of that number"?  That makes sense, and the most straight forward think would be to look at some single bee trips, take the average, and declare that the variable is Poisson with that average.  I have no idea how accurate such a thing would be, though.  You could compare sigmas to get a sense of that.
